# Scrapy dont_proxy meta key

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, scrapy

I am using Scrapy with Crawlera, but for some reasons I would like to switch off Crawlera for some requests and switch on for anothers. I have found `dont_proxy` meta key which seems to be created for such purposes, but when I use it, I get 407 response from Crawlera which (as far as I understand) means proxy authorization error, so that solution obviously not enough. What is the correct way to switch Crawlera on and off on the go?

Comment: are you sure that `407` response comes from Crawlera? please share the response body and headers.

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure it comes from Crawlera. response body is empty and there are headers: {b'Date': [b'Wed, 10 Jan 2018 22:44:58 GMT'], b'Proxy-Authenticate': [b'Basic realm="Crawlera"'], b'X-Crawlera-Error': [b'bad_proxy_auth'], b'X-Crawlera-Version': [b'1.30.39-325aa6']}

Comment: you'll have to share your settings, spider and code on how you are making that request.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been caused by "proxy" field in meta. When you add "dont_proxy" to your meta, crawlera doesnt handle it anymore but "proxy" field is still in meta, causing 407 response. so I post here my solution for everyone who has met the same issue:

```
class ShutdownCrawleraMiddleware(object):
    proxy = 'http://proxy.crawlera.com:8010'
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if hasattr(request, 'meta'):
            if request.meta.get('dont_proxy') is True:
                if request.meta.get('proxy'):
                    request.meta.pop('proxy')
            else:
                if not request.meta.get('proxy'):
                    request.meta['proxy'] = self.proxy
```

This middleware priority should be higher than CrawleraMiddleware's one.